# Unescape string in JavaScript (without using JSON.parse)

Tags: javascript, split, escaping

I am trying to unscape a string (get the original \t character).

I have been trying all this:

```js
var s = "my \t string";
var t = "\\t"; // Backslashes are escaped because this is rendered on an <input>

// How do we split the string?

s.split(t); // ["my      string"]
s.split(t.substring(1)); // Not working becuase t.substring(1) is just 't'
s.split(t.replace(/\\\\/g, "\\")); // ["my   string"]

// Expected result would be:

s.split('\t'); // ["my ", " string"]

// Using JSON.parse works

s.split(JSON.parse('"' + t + '"')); // ["my ", " string"]
```

Is JSON.parse the only way of doing it?

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid JSON.parse?

Comment: @JohnDvorak No special reason. Just trying to know if this is the only approach (or the best one in any case).

Comment: The backslash notation is a convention of the JavaScript parser. The actual tab character is a valid character in its own right, and that's what you actually want in the string.

Comment: @Pointy is correct `\t` only *represents* a tab character in the context of a string literal. A tab character, however, is still a character: `" "` (string containing a tab character). If you do `"some\ttext".split(" ")` then that still works because both represent the same thing. Copy paste in the console to see.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, after thinking a bit more about it, it's clear that there's no other way than just parse or evaluate the string to actually get the "tab" special character, either using JSON.parse or eval. Question can be closed.

Comment: @jllodra you can also simply search for a literal `\t` occurrence in strings and replace it with a tab character `text.replace(/\\t/g, "\t")`. But I'm still not sure what your goal is here.